# Any mobile food diary?

Tags: android, diary

I need as simple as possible daily food diary allowing me to track my daily diet in details.

Requirements:

- an ability to provide food name (either free text or *Sweets > Cakes > Apple pie*-like selection),
- an ability to provide amount of food actually consumed,
- remembering date and time with each entry -- *nice-to-have*, but not necessary,
- having diet database and calculating calories, fat, carbs etc. -- *nice-to-have*, but not necessary,
- free or paid.

What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm from Poland, I ended up choosing a local, Polish product (VitaScale).

However, there is a quite large (yet not very easy to go through) [list of mobile applications for Android](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/health_weight) that includes:

- loose-weight helper applications,
- dietary calendars,
- calorie calculators etc.

It is made by one of SR's users, Izzy. You will most definitely find a software that matches your expectations among this list.